# JavaScript - Nested functions in eval not working with try/catch block

Tags: javascript, try-catch, eval

I have the following code to run in an `eval()`:

```
const code = `
    async function func() {
        asd();
    }

    func();
`;

try {
    console.log("running code");
    return eval(code);
}
catch (err) {
    console.log("error");
    return err.message;
}
```

In this case, `asd` is `undefined`, and so I would expect a reference error to be returned as a string (`return err.message;`). However, instead of the catch block firing, an exception is thrown as if there is no try/catch block. But, if I were to run `eval("asd()")`, the `catch` block would catch the error and return a string. Is there something different I need to do for nested functions?

Note: This entire code is in an async function due to other code (before `const code ...`), if that makes a difference.

Comment: I actually do receive `Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: asd is not defined`.  It seems like there is code missing here though (returns not inside function body).  `async` functions do return a promise btw. You will need to chain the result of the eval (as a promise) to get the result properly.  Also, I would note this:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Do_not_ever_use_eval!

Comment: @Goblinlord Just made an edit to add a note, maybe that makes a difference? And as for the safety note, don't worry, only I can execute this code.

Comment: @Goblinlord Could you provide an example of what you mean by chaining the result of the eval?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to handle eval as a promise since you are using a promise inside it.

```js
const asyncEval = () => {
  const code = `
    async function func() {
        asd();
    }

    func();
`;

    console.log("running code");
    return Promise.resolve(eval(code));
}

const ele = document.getElementById('result');

asyncEval()
  .then(res => {
    ele.innerText = res;
  })
  .catch(err => {
    ele.innerText = "ERROR: " + err;
  })
```

```html
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

To ensure it works if there is a promise returned or not you can do `Promise.resolve(eval(code))` instead of `eval(code)`.

Either way, I would also recommend reading this and not using eval:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Do_not_ever_use_eval!